# Python requests module not working with Proxy when trying to access HTTPS sites

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to use premium proxy ip's to connect to a website using requests module but it does not work with 'https' sites.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
auth=HTTPProxyAuth('username','password')
proxies={
'http':'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/',
'https':'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/'
}
print(requests.get('https://www.google.com',proxies=proxies,auth=auth).status_code)
```

The following error is thrown:

```
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com',port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))
```

Note:I have tried using various monkey patches which suggest Digest Auth even from 7 years ago but none of them seem to work.

Edit 1:

I am not using the http://username@password:ip:port/ format for using proxy because my username contains '@' which causes a parsing error.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this

```
http://username@password:ip:port/
```

You mentioned that your password consists special characters

'@' can be replaced with '%40'

For example ,

'Pass@word' can be replaced with 'Pass%40word'

The below data might be helpful if you some more special characters in your password

```
'@' = '%40'
'%' ='%25'
'#' = '%23'
'@' = '%40'
':' = '%3a'
';' = '%3b'
'?' = '%3f'
'$' = '%24'
'!' = '%21'
'/' = '%2f'
'\' = '%27'
'"' = '%22'
```